# transition between is and iOS 8 using NSString imageURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode6

new to iOS development,

app worked fine in iOS 7 upon the release of iOS 8, my app wouldn't open, i set a breakpoit that led me to the home screen and this line.  It appears that there is an issue pulling the image from the url which is correct.  The Xcode output is - UIImageView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]:  Im struggling to find a solve for it

[cell.ImageLabel setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]

Here is a bit more code setting the data

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];

_Images = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://w***.jpg?month=%i&year=%i", month, year],
                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://***.jpg?month=%i&year=%i", month, year],
                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://***.jpg?month=%i&year=%i", month, year],
                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://***.jpg?month=%i&year=%i", month, year],
                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://***.jpg?month=%i&year=%i", month, year],
                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://***.jpg?month=%i&year=%i", month, year],
                 @"television.png"];
```

this is the code to configure the cell:

// Configure the cell...

```
int row = [indexPath row];
cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
cell.DescLabel.text = _Description[row];

NSString *imageURL = _Images[row];
if(row < 6){
    [cell.ImageLabel setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"]];
} else {
cell.ImageLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_Images[row]];
}


return cell;
```

Comment: There's no -[UIImageView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:] in UIKit, so you might want to specify what library you are using

Comment: @FabioRitrovato there is one… AFNetworking 1.3.3

Comment: in the last version of AFNetworking (2.x.x) this method is unchanged... I tested 1.3 and it's working well. Try to log your imageUrl, maybe there is the issue...

Comment: sorry what do you mean by log the imageUrl?

Comment: I mean… to check if the url is correct retuned

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code would help you,

```
int row = [indexPath row];
cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
cell.DescLabel.text = _Description[row];

NSString *stringUrl = _Images[row];
        NSURL *urlStr = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];

        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library assetForURL:urlStr resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
         {

             __block UIImage *assetThumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset];
             dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

             dispatch_async(queue, ^{

                 UIImage *image = assetThumbnailImage;
                 assetThumbnailImage = nil;

                 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                     cell.ImageLabel.image = image;

                 });
             });


         }
                failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
         {
             // error handling
             NSLog(@"failure-----");
         }];
```